# typeahead multiline List items

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

i am using typeahead using twitter bootstrap and angularjs .its showing autocomplete suggestions as shown in below screenshot.but i want to show big cities name in different lines.for example London Borough of Harrow in two lines using twitter bootstrap typehead .How to acheive that ??any help is appreciable i am using http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ .

[image]

Comment: You mean for the text to wrap over multiple lines?

Comment: correct but wrap-word is not working

Comment: you need to give that orange bar a higher `z-index` than the blue area. I wouldn't worry about word wrapping

Answer (score 1):

Just put a <br> tag where you want the line to break.

Answer (score 0):

you can have template for this

```
<input id="id" type="text" name="name" ng-model="binding" typeahead-min-length="0" uib-typeahead="x as x.name for xyz in alphabet" typeahead-popup-template-url="url/to/template" typeahead-editable="false" autocomplete="off" typeahead-on-select="yourMethodCall()" ng-change="yourMethodCall()">
```

**in your template file i.e. some_template.html**

```
<div class="design class" aria-hidden="{{!isOpen()}}">
    <div class="container" ng-repeat="match in matches">
      <div> your design here... </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and boom you are done